# Alter the MATE menu bar to change text

Tags: 16.04, menu, mate

The Menu Bar of MATE in 16.04 text reads 
Applications Places System

How may I change that to read 
Apps GoTo Syst
to release more panel space for other uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See - [Change the text for “Applications, Places, System”](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/change-the-text-for-applications-places-system/10465)

1. get a copy of the PO file for `mate-panel` for your locale from the [source code.](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-panel/tree/master/po)

   (On GitHub, click on the file, then the Raw button, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save)
2. Install `poedit` using `sudo apt install poedit` or from Boutique (under Programming).
3. Open Poedit and find the "Applications", "Places", "System" lines and change them to what you want. Save the new PO file; this will also create a MO file.
4. Copy the new MO file to the system locales folder (here using `en_GB` as an example locale):

   ```
   sudo cp en_GB.mo /usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/mate-panel.mo
   ```
5. Restart the panel -- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type:

   ```
   mate-panel --replace
   ```